# Serializing inside PgwModal returns empty values

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

I want users to be able to register themselfs inside a modal (pgwmodal.js). Serializing the form returns keys with empty values even though they are filled in.

HTML

```
<div id="modal-register" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="input width_50">
                <label for="register_input_first_name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="register_input_first_name" id="register_input_first_name">
                <input type="text" name="register_input_last_name" id="register_input_last_name">
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label for="register_input_email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="register_input_email" id="register_input_email">
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label for="register_input_password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="register_input_password" id="register_input_password">
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <button id="button_register" type="button" class="button button-primary">Create user</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // create modal
    $('.register-trigger').click(function() {
        $.pgwModal({
            target: '#modal-register',
            title: 'New user',
            maxWidth: 970
        });
    });

    // serialize when button is clicked
    $(document).on("click", "#button_register", function() {
        console.log($('#modal-register form').serialize());
        $.post("functions/func_register.php",$('#modal-register form').serialize(),
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, 'json');
    });

});
```

I think I somehow need to update #modal-register with the contents of the modal. If I fill in every field of the form, the serialize function give the following response:

register_input_first_name=&register_input_last_name=&register_input_email=&register_input_password=